# Why is this pandas data frame not updating with the new prices each time it loops?

Tags: python, pandas, cryptocurrency, coingecko

How do I make it so that when I go through this loop, the data frame is updated each time with the new price data?

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import pycoingecko
cg = pycoingecko.CoinGeckoAPI()

for i in range(10):
    df = pd.DataFrame(cg.get_coin_ticker_by_id(id='bitcoin').get('tickers'))
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: You are just creating a new dataframe at each iteration, what you should do is to append a row to the existing dataframe.

Comment: What do you mean? I want to use the entire data frame but the data is not updating every couple of seconds

Comment: Does coingecko actually update the data every two seconds?

Comment: I have tried it with 10 seconds as well. The volume data is not changing in the data frame either.

Answer (score 0):

You just creating another dataframe and dont keep information from the previous loop. You should concatenate dataframes.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import pycoingecko
cg = pycoingecko.CoinGeckoAPI()
df= pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(10):
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(cg.get_coin_ticker_by_id(id='bitcoin').get('tickers'))])        
    time.sleep(2)
```

Creating new dataframe each time:

```
list = []
for i in range(10):
    df=pd.DataFrame(cg.get_coin_ticker_by_id(id='bitcoin').get('tickers'))
    list.append(df)       
    time.sleep(2)
```

Here **list** elements are dataframes.

Comment: While this works, it is adding to the current data frame. I want it to make a new data frame each time. Do you know how I would go about doing this?

Comment: You can just append dataframes to a list, answer edited.